# Square root of negative number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was reading my school's math textbooks for the next semester, and I found that when $a >0,$ $\sqrt{(-a)^2}=a$, but $\sqrt{(-a)^2}=\sqrt{a^2}i^2=-a$. So which one is right?

Comment: $i=\sqrt{-1}$ also called the imaginary number

Comment: $i^2$ is indeed -1. But consider the difference between $-1(a)^2$ and $(-1a)^2$. In the order of operations, exponentation takes precedence before multiplication.  Edit: to clarify, your mistake is that you seem to think $-1(a)^2$ is equivalent to $(-1a)^2$ or is its factored form. But that isn't true.

Comment: I don’t even know how you get from $\sqrt{(-a)^2}$ to $\sqrt{a^2} i^2$. Neither is $(-a)^2 = i^2 a^2$ nor can you pull $i^2$ out of the root.

Comment: @user441343: Notice, $\sqrt{(-a)^2}=|-a|$ $$|-a|=\begin{cases} -(-a)= a\ \ \forall\ \ a>0\\  (-a)= -a\ \ \forall\ \ a<0  \end{cases}$$

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Why does the square root of an integer always be a positive number?

Comment: PS: I guess you “calculated” $\sqrt{(-a)^2} = \sqrt{(i^2 a)^2} = \sqrt{i^4 a^2} = \sqrt{i^4} \sqrt{a^2} = i^2 \sqrt{a^2}$, in which case you made the mistake of assuming $\sqrt{i^4} = i^2$. It is also generally a bad idea to take the square root of numbers which are not real and positive, as long as you don’t know what you’re doing. (If you are wondering if you know what you’re doing then you are not.)

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Now I finally understood. Thank you

Comment: no they are not always postivie there are negative as well the posivite part is taken

Comment: @user49557 I don't understand. I know that there should also be negative numbers but I'm not sure.

Comment: ok every postive numbers ahs 2 real squeare roots one positive and negative like root of 16 is 4 and - 4

Comment: becuase 4 * 4 = 16    ,-4 * -4 = 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a key point here is that the square root function isn't well defined without making choices. Since 2 numbers square to any given nonzero number ($a^2=(-a)^2$), the square root is ambiguous unless you arbitrarily pick one. When dealing with the real numbers, it was decided to always pick the positive root. So $\sqrt{(a)^2}=|a|$ and $\sqrt{(-a)^2}=|a|$ for any real $a$.

As soon as you start dealing with complex numbers, things get more complicated. I don't know how to explain the fine details without a bunch of complex analysis but an important consequence is that you can't always say many things that feel like they should be true, such as: $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ or $\sqrt{a^2}=\sqrt{a}^2$ or any other formula that might get you from  $\sqrt{(-a)^2}$ to $\sqrt{a^2}i^2$

Answer (score 0):

> $a >0,$ $\sqrt{(-a)^2}=a$

This is correct, because $(-a)^2 = (-1)^2 a^2 = a^2$ and $\sqrt{a^2} = a$.

> $\sqrt{(-a)^2}=\sqrt{a^2}i^2=-a$

This is not correct, because $\sqrt{(-a)^2} = a$ different from $\sqrt{a^2} i^2 = a (-1) = -a$.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is that $b=\sqrt a$ means that $b$ is the non-negative solution $x$ of $x^2=a$. The square-root notation $\sqrt a$ is usually avoided unless $ a$ is a non-negative real number,  because of ambiguities. It's always good to check the definition, before trying any algebraic calculations. When someone first wrote $b=\sqrt a$ he had to explain exactly what that said about $b$.